# Does the word "again" have a tense?

Tags: adjectives, tenses, adverbs

In a recent conversation, the mention of one politician's use of 'again' prompted a relative to say " 'Again' is past tense."

*Can* the word "again" be assigned past (or present) tense?

Context: Someone told me that they thought the slogan "Make America Great Again", "Keep America Great Again" was past tense with reference to the word 'again' and that this was backwards thinking.

I'm just an aspiring wordsmith, curious to the nuances in play here.

Comment: You need a pair of commas to surround a parenthetical expression. So the semicolon doesn't fit.

Comment: Welcome. But you will be more welcome (to me at least) if you finish reading the [tour] and the help on asking questions. Could you edit your question, cutting the irrelevances, and just state clearly what your question about the English language is. Leave your wife and your neighbours out of it. At the moment I have little idea what your question is about.

Comment: Thank you for your "helpful" comments David. I had the same thoughts, although if you were to read through it again without being so critical as to my verbosity I trust you would figure it out.  Just saying man.  Just saying.

Comment: Thank you to each of you who have helped me refine my question with the suggestions and edits.

Comment: VERBS have "tenses" - but ***again*** isn't a verb.

Answer (score 3):

While, looking at this strictly, no tense can be assigned to any parts of speech other than verbs, and so the frequency adverb 'again' has no more a tense than it does sidewhiskers, broadened usages often occur and often become established, acceptable. From the internet I've collected several examples where 'is past tense' is used informally to mean 'is history', 'is no more', 'is confined to the past'. This is a typical metaphorical broadening.

- 'Peak Oil is Past Tense': Exxon, Shell, and Aramco Admit the Peak is Real ... The IEA's Chief Economist Fatih Birol declared: Peak Oil is here, or rather, was here in 2006. And it really doesn't matter whose analysis you prefer....
- a fund for clean energy, oil barons are ... past tense [[Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22are+past+tense%22+%22is+history%22&ei=oY1fX9yPENXCxgP356fYDg&start=60&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwic5Oe2_OjrAhVVoXEKHffzCesQ8tMDegQIDRA3&biw=1319&bih=750)]
- But beauty parlours are past tense.
- You can’t change yesterday but you can enjoy today and you can determine your tomorrow!  All of your yesterdays are gone … they are past tense. [[Carol Mcleod](https://www.carolmcleodministries.com/a-cup-of-tea-with-carol/today)]
- 'The hair is gon.' ... Yep, that's the first thing coming up to my mind, when I see good old Willie [Nelson] standing up there on stage at the Circus Krone in Munich. Mind me, his long plaits were something like his brand. But they are past tense now. [[MusicMirror_Reviews](http://www.musicmirror.de/reviewsearchives554.htm)]

So " 'Again' is past tense" ( for "If we use the word 'again', it means we're revisiting the same old ideas / plans / projects that didn't work too well back in the day") is pithy, witty, and better than acceptable on one level. But not in a linguistics class.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "Make [noun] [adjective] Again" means that [noun] was once [adjective], and then was not , and the speaker wants it to be [adjective] in the future.

There isn't, in the mere statement, any implication that the speaker wants to go "backwards". If you were talking about a company that was the biggest in the world, and you wanted to make it the biggest in the world again, that wouldn't mean going backwards necessarily. Remember I am making statements only about grammar.

"Keep [noun] [adjective] Again" implies that [noun] has been kept [adjective] before, and that we want to do it again. It's a bit of doubtful grammaticality in the example you cite (when was the time that America was *kept* great before?), but for slogans 'nice-sounding' overrides 'grammatical'.

Comment: Yup,it ain't go back again.

Comment: lol. that is funny.